# how can i write API that saves the json file as a json into the database

Tags: django-rest-framework

How to insert the JSON file I have, into the database through API? I've tried surfing many online websites and online videos only thing I found is adding data manually into the database

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: @sam I have some text file which contains JSON data, now I need to access that file and save the JSON data into database this is to be done through rest API